# Finding the average from a mapped list of int

Tags: scala, mapping

I am trying to get the average from a mapped list of ints, then return that value to the user when requested.
Here is my current code with problems, what am I doing wrong? I have included my functionality to find the last element of a tail, that works.

```
// *******************************************************************************************************************
  // application logic
    // read data from file
  val mapdata = readFile("data.txt")




  // *******************************************************************************************************************
  // UTILITY FUNCTIONS
  //GETS THE DATA FROM THE DATA.TXT
  def readFile(filename: String): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
    processInput(Source.fromFile(filename).getLines)
  }
  def processInput(lines: Iterator[String]): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
    Try {
      lines.foldLeft(Map[String, List[Int]]()) { (acc, line) =>

        val splitline = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList
        acc.updated(splitline.head, splitline.tail.map(_.toInt))
      }
    }.getOrElse {
      println("Sorry, an exception happened.")
      Map()
    }
  }



  //functionality to find the last tail element
  def findLast(list:List[Int]):Int = {
    if(list.tail == Nil)
      list.head
    else
      findLast(list.tail)
  }

  //Function to find the average
  def average(list:List[Int]):Double =
    list.foldLeft(0.0)(_+_) / list.foldLeft(0)((r,c)=>r+1)



 //Show last element in the list, most current WORKS
  def currentStockLevel (stock: String): (String, Int) = {
    (stock, mapdata.get (stock).map(findLast(_)).getOrElse(0))
  }

  //Show last element in the list, most current DOES NOT WORK
  def averageStockLevel (stock: String): (String, Int) = {
    (stock, mapdata.get (stock).map(average(_)).getOrElse(0))
  }
```

my txt file

```
SK1, 9, 7, 2, 0, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1
SK2, 0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1
SK4, 2, 9, 5, 7, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 5, 4, 0, 9, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8
SK5, 2, 6, 8, 0, 3, 5, 5, 2, 5, 9, 4, 5, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 2, 5, 9, 3, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 4, 1, 2, 3
```

The error that I am getting is that expression of type AnyVal does not conform to type Int

Comment: Please tell me where is the problem. Did you get any compilation error ? Did you get wrong result ? What does you data.txt contains ?

Comment: How is the data laid out in the data.txt ?

Comment: Tried to include everything relevant, forgot about the data file... smooth one Andre, have added it to the question including error that I get @pamu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `averageStockLevel` function returns the average value as an `Int` (the return type is `(String, Int)`) whereas the calculation  that is done in `average` returns a `Double`.

So you either need to convert the calculated `Double` to an `Int` within `averageStockLevel` (e.g. by doing `average(_).toInt`), or you can change the return type of `averageStockLevel` to `(String, Double)`. The latter variant is obviously the better one since you don't loose the precision of your average value.

```
def averageStockLevel (stock: String): (String, Double) = {
  (stock, mapdata.get(stock).map(average).getOrElse(0.0))
}
```

This works, but whether or not it's a good idea to return `0.0` in case of a missing key is for you to decide. Another possibility is to omit the `getOrElse` part and return an `Option[(String,Double)]`.

Apart from that, your code is quite complex. `findLast` and `average` can be defined much easier (it's not really worth it to create an own function for finding the last element, but for the sake of completeness...):

```
// will throw an exception for empty lists, but so does your current code
def findLast(list:List[Int]) = list.last 

def average(list:List[Int]): Double = list.sum.toDouble / list.size
```

Another idea is to replace `List` by `Vector`. For operations such as `.size` and `.last`, `List` needs linear time whereas `Vector` basically takes constant time.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why it didn't work, really helped me understand. Obviously cant return a double as an int, and thanks for the solution as well!